# How to Filter Large Data Set

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like, large-data

I would assume that this should be handled on the data base server instead of using the Apache server in my specific case, but I'm wondering about how I would filter a result set that could be at least one hundred thousand records or greater.

On the interface side, a user would see the first page of results (like 100 results on say, invoices) where they can filter the result set or sort by the columns. The way I've done this system in the past was to create a MySQL command comparing each of the visible columns with the search term surrounded by the percent sign and using `like` for the comparison. My only problem was that this seemed to be quite slow even when processing a database that was around the 300MB mark.

Since I'm relatively new to database performance and was unable to find any filtering strategies, how should I structure my queries to provide quick, filtered data?

Comment: `LIKE` queries are incredibly slow. Quick suggestoin: If possible, you could make some of the visible columns a dropdown, so you could easily do a `=` query.

Comment: Try reading about MySQL indexes. You're right about the filtering being done in the database.

Comment: Say the data set could be split by like a company ID, and there's maybe 20 company IDs available, if I used a drop down for a company to split the data set into a 20th of the size, would that make my `LIKE` on other fields faster?